# Need help converting Visual Studio 2008 MSBuild Script to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a simple MSBuild Script that looks like this.

```
  ...
  <Target Name="CompileSolution">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(VS90COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\devenv.exe&quot; ..\MyProject.All.sln /build" />
  </Target>
  ...
```

Now I migrated the propect to Visual Studio 2010 and the command fails.

```
  ...
  <Target Name="CompileSolution">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\devenv.exe&quot; ..\MyProject.All.sln /build" />
  </Target>
  ...
```

because the variable `$(VS100COMNTOOLS)` is empty. I verified that with

```
<Exec Command="echo $(VS100COMNTOOLS)" />
```

and I checked that the environment variable "VS100COMNTOOLS" exists. If I modify the command to use the full path to `devenv.exe` rather than the variable, everything works fine. But that's just a temporary solution since the devenv path differs for my collegues.

What is the best way to query the `VS100COMNTOOLS` path in a Visual Studio 2010 MSBuild Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is any use, but instead of using visual studion to build you can just use an msbuild itself, here any example:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CoreBuild">
  <Message text="Core Build"/>
  <MSBuild Projects ="@(ProjectsToBuild)" 
           ContinueOnError ="false" 
           Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" >
      <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
  </MSBuild>
</Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="**\*sln" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem but that looks like that's exactly what I want to achive, thanks.

Comment: the method also allows if you have a big build you can things like the "/m" switch which can runs the build over multiple cores.

Comment: @SchlaWiener Actually when you execute build in visual studio - backward transformation occurs - visual studio transforms sln file to MSBuild build file and execute corresponding targets. You can read a bit more detailed info here (or in other articles on that blog): http://sedodream.com/2010/10/22/MSBuildExtendingTheSolutionBuild.aspx

Comment: @Alexey, I know. But the initial problem was, that the `$(VS90COMNTOOLS)` variable don't exist in VS2010 and changing it to `$(VS100COMNTOOLS)` didn't work either. Since our dev team uses both, x86 and x64 operating systems, changing the var to the full path to `devenv.exe` is not a good solution. However, using the target CoreBuild seems be a better solution anyway but haven't tried it out, yet.